# ¿Cómo pasar un campo de un modelo a otro en mvc.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

> Tengo un modelo cliente donde le guardo el valor por hora y cuando en el formulario de orden de servicio seleccione el nombre del cliente me traiga el campo valor por hora como lo muestra la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como estas obteniendo el nombre del cliente en OrdenServicios/Create?. Esto es para saber de que manera te podría colaborar.

Comment: // GET: OrdenServicios/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Clientes, "ClienteId", "Nombre");
            return View();
        }

Comment: me devuelve nulo  // GET: OrdenServicios/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Clientes, "ClienteId", "ValorHora");
            return View();
        }

Comment: Creo que ya te entiendo. Lo que necesitas es que cuando estes creando una orden de servicio nueva, si seleccionan un cliente del  'select' aparezca el valor x hora en el 'input' correspondiente. Pero cuando se abra la página de crear te traiga por defecto el valor x hora del cliente que está seleccionado en ese momento. Es esto correcto?

Comment: si exacto!!!!!!!

Comment: Yonder, Ahi tienes varias cosas por solucionar. Voy a intentar colaborarte con la parte de que cuando seleccionen un cliente te traiga el valor, pero para eso vamos a necesitar la libreria de Javascript JQuery. Utilizas JQuery en tu proyecto?, Si no es así lo puedes instalar desde Nuget.

Comment: ok yo tengo la librería anexado en el proyecto

Comment: Cuando abres el Create no se deberia obtener ningun valor. Sino como lo estan recomendando al momento de seleccionar en el cliente el combo/lista desplegable tendrias que ir al servidor al traer todo lo necesario (hoy es solamente el tema de ValorXHora pero podria ser otros campos necesarios para autocompletar)
Tengo una pregunta, el campo se "autocompleta" pero el usuario lo puede modificar a ese valor que lo colocas en el textbox de ValorXHora no?

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar esto, vamos a revisar tres partes de tu proyecto, los controladores, el html y el javascript.

1. **Controladores:** Debes tener función dentro del controlador, que tenga mas o menos lo siguiente:

> ```
> public JsonResult ClientePorId(int idCliente)
> {
>     // Debes obtener un objeto desde la base de datos con la información del cliente que se seleccionó. 
>     var cliente = ObtenerClientePorId(idCliente);
>     return Json(cliente);
> }
> ```

2. **HTML:** Debes revisar que el select en el HTML tenga un id y el input tambien:

```html
<select id="clientes" ... >....</select>
<input id="valorxhora" ... ></input>
```

3. **Javascript:** Cunado cambie el valor del select, se debe ejecutar la siguiente función:

```js
$("#clientes").change(function(){
  //Se llama a la función que se creo en el controlador
  var url = "<UrldelControlador>/ClientePorId";
  var params = {idCliente:$("clientes").val()};
  $.post(url, params)
  .done(function(result){
    //result.valorxhora lo tienes que reemplazar por en nombre de la propiedad que estas retornando.
    $("#valorxhora").val(result.valorxhora)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría mas simple de la siguiente forma:

1. En el controller en el metodo Create del actionResult, le agregaría un método de soporte que recupere el valor (valor X Hora). Ya sea con ADO, Linq o Entity (entiendo que es un valor almacenado en la base de datos).
   el valor recuperado lo coloco en un ViewData para enviarlo a la vista donde lo inserto en el html del control.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En la vista podrá recuperar el valor enviado. con un código muy similar a este. (Supongo que es Razor)

```html
@Html.TextBox("ValorPorHora", ViewData["ValorPorHora"]
```

Mostrando el valor recuperado de la base de datos y que viaja usando el método ViewData.